# Function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, funções

Preciso criar uma `Function()` no meu banco `PostgreSQL` para que toda vez que houver uma movimentação de `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` em determinada tabela seja ativada essa função através de uma `TRIGGER` para que nessa minha tabela de log fiquem armazenadas todos os movimentos que o produto tenha sofrido. Criei a seguinte `Function`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_suprimentoslog()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
begin
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        IF (NEW.numeroserie <> OLD.numeroserie) THEN
            INSERT INTO suprimentoslog (codigoestoque, numeroserie, dataoperacao, clienteempresa, clienteusuario, solicitante, operacao)
            values
            (new.codigoestoque, new.numeroserie, current_date, ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', 'ALTERACAO SUPRIMENTO') 
            return new;
        END IF;
    end if;
    if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        INSERT INTO suprimentoslog (codigoestoque, numeroserie, dataoperacao, clienteempresa, clienteusuario, solicitante, operacao)
        values
        (new.codigoestoque, new.numeroserie, current_date, ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', 'ENTRADA SUPRIMENTO') 
        return new;
    end if;
    return null;
end
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Porém a mesma me retorna o seguinte erro quando tento executá-la:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 11:    return new;
            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "return"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 411
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta colocar o ponto e vírgula no final dos `INSERT`. Ex:

```
INSERT INTO suprimentoslog (
codigoestoque
, numeroserie
, dataoperacao
, clienteempresa
, clienteusuario
, solicitante
, operacao)
values
(new.codigoestoque
, new.numeroserie
, current_date
, ' - '
, ' - '
, ' - '
, 'ALTERACAO SUPRIMENTO'); --Aqui
```